# Toggle logged in effect in PHP

Tags: toggle, admin, effect

I have built my admin options within the page so if the admin is logged in all the text boxes and images can be changed on the same page.

Is it possible to add a link so when clicked it will toggle the effect of being logged in and logged out without actually logging out?

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,sorry for late update,

to solve the problem i used jquery

created divs to go around all admin options and then just used the toggle option to show and hide them when admin click on the "show admin" option